# C# software freezing when setting property to true

Tags: c#, class, properties, freeze

I have the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // our config
    public bool runBot, afkModeToggle, shutdownPcToggle = false;
    public int roundsToPlay, minsToPlay, waitInLobbyFor, waitInDeathScreenFor;

    public void addToLogs(string logmsg)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("\r\n" + logmsg);
        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }

    public void startsoftware()
    {
        runBot = true;
        addToLogs("[" + DateTime.Now + "] Bot has started");
        label22.Text = " RUNNING" + runBot;
        label22.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
    }

    public void pausesoftware()
    {
        runBot = false;
        addToLogs("[" + DateTime.Now + "] Bot has been paused");
        label22.Text = " PAUSED" + runBot;
        label22.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Crimson;

        if (checkBox3.Checked) 
        { 
            Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
        }
    }

    public bool processrunning()
    {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        if (pname.Length == 0)
        {
            label23.Text = "process Not Found";
            label23.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Crimson;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            label23.Text = "process Found";
            label23.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
            return true;
        }
    }

    //
    // form follows
    //

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while(runBot == true)
        {
            if(processrunning() == true)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startsoftware();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pausesoftware();
    }
}
```

It is a basic form built via visual studio. When I click the button1 it just freezes the software and you cant click on anything else. I have traced it down to this - if I comment out the `runBot = true` inside the `startsoftware` function it will work however having that line is causing the freeze.

Im I missing something here?

Comment: where is `runBot` used? is it used on another thread or not?

Comment: You need to post all _relevant_ code, see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: how is this not the minimal code? there is nothing else.. I declare a variable and set its value

Comment: Do you debug it, and step through each line? Also wrap it in a try catch.

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't understand what that  means. it is used in the method shown above

Comment: Where is it read at?

Comment: @Vandel212 no errors, just a freeze/crash

Comment: @DanielA.White its assigned to label22.

Comment: i feel like there is more to it.  Is there any control on the form that is "listening" for the botRun value to be changed?

Comment: The reason people are asking for more information is that the code you've posted works correctly, so the problem must be happening somewhere else. You need to step through your code and see where it's hanging (set a breakpoint on the assignment and then use F10/F11 to step through the code). At a minimum, press the "pause" button in Visual Studio when it's hanging so you can see which line is executing.

Comment: Put a line break in it, and debug.

Comment: @dfdsfsd I find it very hard to believe that this is all your code.  Half of your class variables arent assigned or referenced in the example you've posted.  Plus ignoring the fact that running the code you have posted results in no errors

Comment: as requested, I have pasted the whole code in. I have put breakpoints on the line runBot = true and theres no errors

Comment: @maccettura huh? I didn't say it was all my code.. anyways updated questions. and as I said theres no runtime errors? paste it and tell me what errors you get on your end then since your so determined?

Comment: @RufusL ive said, its hanging on the runBot = true line.

Comment: don't put a loop in the timer tick. `runBot` should just be the `Enabled` property on the timer.

Comment: @DanielA.White is right. You are probably starting tens of thousands of loop right now which create race condition PLUS you actually changed the text on a GUI object from within the timer thread.

Comment: Yeah, I know you said that, but I copied and pasted your (original) code into a project and it ran fine.

Comment: @Franck that's fine with a timer.

Comment: @DanielA.White no because the timer must still tick even if runBot is set to false. does this seem correct? is there a problem to using the runBot instead of enabled property?

Comment: also, are you sayings its not possible to have loops in a timer?

Answer (score 0):

Windows forms have a UI thread.  This thread is responsible for updating the UI, and handling UI related events.  If this thread ever becomes blocked then your UI will become unresponsive.

The timer tick event is handled by this UI thread, so when you start a long loop inside this event handler the UI thread is unable to process the rest of the UI and your program appears to freeze.

There are several ways to fix this in your code.  You might remove the

```
while(runBot == true)
```

from your timer tick event, and let the timer tick periodically.  You could disable the timer when you don't want the `processrunning` check to run. 
 You could disable buttons if there's something you don't want the user to click during this time.

Another option would be to have a background thread that calls `processrunning` and sets a flag accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Something needs to change in this portion of the code or you will loop forever:

```
while(runBot == true)
{
    if(processrunning() == true)
    {
    }
}
```

Perhaps set runbot to false in the processing?